# Speed up Rake Cucumber test run in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rake, spring-gem

I'd like to use Cucumber via Rake for BDD in a Rails 4. I've got it installed and hooked into `spring` to speed up tests but they take much longer than expected to run. The tests definitively run faster when Spring is active, but there is always ~2 seconds of startup time for Cucumber even if there are no feature/scenarios to run. For example:

```
$ bin/spring status
Spring is not running.

$ time bin/rake cucumber
/Users/alans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
bin/rake cucumber  0.08s user 0.02s system 3% cpu 3.463 total

$ bin/spring status
Spring is running:
64383 spring server | cucumber_test | started 48 secs ago
64384 spring app    | cucumber_test | started 48 secs ago | test mode    

$ time bin/rake cucumber
/Users/alans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
bin/rake cucumber  0.08s user 0.02s system 4% cpu 2.098 total
```

Using `bin/rake` for the run is what's defined in the [Spring Readme](https://github.com/rails/spring#usage). Running spring without rake produces the faster expected times.

```
$ time spring cucumber
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
spring cucumber  0.06s user 0.01s system 13% cpu 0.537 total
```

---

### The Question

**How can I setup Cucumber, Spring and Rake so that tests run as quickly with Rake as without?**

---

---

**Further Details**

My environment is an RVM install of ruby-2.1.1 and rails 4.1.1 on a Mac with an SSD running 10.9.3.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create an app with

   ```
   rails new cucumber_test -T
   ```
2. Update the gem file with the following:

   ```
   group :development, :test do

     gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
     gem 'database_cleaner'
     gem 'rspec-rails'
     gem 'spring'
     gem 'spring-commands-cucumber'

   end
   ```

   Then running:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```

   (*I also tried leaving the default listing for `spring` in just the :development environment but that didn't speed things up either.*)
3. Run the Cucumber generator:

   ```
   rails g cucumber:install
   ```
4. Update the Spring binstubs:

   ```
   bundle exec spring binstub --all
   ```

   Which returns:

   ```
   * bin/rake: spring already present
   * bin/cucumber: generated with spring 
   * bin/rails: spring already present
   ```

This is where I run the time tests. When Spring is stopped, Cucumber consistently takes longer to run. Even with Spring running it seems there is always a 2 second overhead before the test suite actually kicks off when using Rake. That's what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: why not just use spring cucumber?

Comment: I'd like to use rake so both Cucumber and RSpec tests can be run with a single command.

Comment: I find, to my alarm, that `bin/rake cucumber` takes the same amount of time with or without spring. Editing the generated cucumber tasks to set `fork = false` saves me 2.5s with or without spring. `bin/cucumber` without spring is about as fast as `bin/rake cucumber` with `fork=false` and with or without without spring. `bin/cucumber` with spring is a couple of seconds faster than that, so even with `fork = false` rake is taking a couple of extra seconds.